# Displaying an error message if From date is greater than To date

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to display an error message if from date is greater than to date that is if user gives from date as-31/05/2016 and if to date as -1/5/2016 i need to display an error msg To date should be greater than from date always from date should be less when compared with to date.

Comment: This looks like you're checking if the absolute difference between the from and to date is more than one year or not.  FYI you could have just used `Math.Abs` instead of formatting to a string, removing the negative sign and parsing back to an `int`.

Comment: already i had used two if conditions,also along with this condition if user gives the date greater than present date i need to display an error message that you cannot select the date greater than todays date.

Comment: `DateTime` implements IComparable so you can check whether the from date is greater than the to date directly after you have them parsed: `if (frmdt > Todt)`

Comment: CompareValidator??

Comment: Here i need to display 3 error messages they are from  date should always be less than to date,user cannot choose the date greater than taodays that is present date and user cannot choose dates greater tha 12 months that is he can select the date between any 12 months but should not exceed 12 months

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using in this way we can display an error message to the user

```
if (DateTime.Compare(fromDate, toDate) > 0)
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "From Date Should Be Less Than To Date";
                return;
            }
            if (DateTime.Compare(fromDate, DateTime.Now) > 0 || DateTime.Compare(toDate, DateTime.Now) > 0)
            {
                //lblMessage.Text = "Date Cannot Be Greater Than Today's Date";
                lblMessage.Text = "Exceeded Today's Date";
                return;
            }
```